# SSIS DB2 connection troubles in Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, db2

I would like to ask question about  connection managers OLE DB Provider. Accidentally i have two copies of OLE DB Provider (Copy1 and Copy2) on my computer. Copy2 is not registered on Server, but if i want to use Copy1  username and password is  gray / non editable. 
Why?  In users DSN i have both – DB DB2COPY1 and DB2COPY2
How can i enable COPY1 to be edited (username and password)  ?
Prints from Visual studio 2015
[image]

If I click on Data Links i see this error

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found!  :)  maybe it will be helpful for someone. First copy was just IBM Server Client Version, Second copy was Server Runtime Client.

So i unistalled both, then install Server Runtime Client as First copy and it works